# Tex Text Inkscape extension: pdflatex do not succeed

Tags: pdftex, miktex, inkscape

Recently I update my Inkscape in my laptop to the new version, also TEX TEXT extension. But now, when I try to create any equation, text, number or another latex command I get the following error:

[image: Error]

Also I uploaded MikTex, and more options. Do you know how can be solved this problem?

Inksacpe version: 1.0 (4035a4fb49, 2020-05-01)
Tex Text: 1.0.1.(Lastest at the github).
MikTex version: 2.9.7429

Edit: Log file information:

```
020-06-21 15:54:06,590+0200 INFO  pdflatex - this process (2032) started by 'pythonw' with command line: "C:\Users\migue\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe" tmp.tex -interaction=nonstopmode -halt-on-error
2020-06-21 15:54:06,613+0200 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2020-06-21 15:54:06,614+0200 INFO  pdflatex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-06-21 15:54:06,708+0200 INFO  pdflatex - going to create file: pdflatex.fmt
2020-06-21 15:54:06,769+0200 INFO  pdflatex.core - start process: initexmf --dump-by-name=pdflatex --engine=pdftex
2020-06-21 15:54:13,341+0200 FATAL pdflatex.core - GUI framework cannot be initialized.
2020-06-21 15:54:13,341+0200 FATAL pdflatex.core - Data: 
2020-06-21 15:54:13,346+0200 FATAL pdflatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\UI\Qt\mikuiqt.cpp:77
2020-06-21 15:54:13,346+0200 FATAL pdflatex - GUI framework cannot be initialized.
2020-06-21 15:54:13,346+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2020-06-21 15:54:13,346+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\UI\Qt\mikuiqt.cpp
2020-06-21 15:54:13,346+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 77
2020-06-21 15:54:13,347+0200 INFO  pdflatex - this process (2032) finishes with exit code 1
2020-06-21 15:54:13,349+0200 FATAL pdflatex - major issue: So far, you have not checked for MiKTeX updates.
2020-06-21 15:54:13,349+0200 WARN  miktex.core - still open: tmp.log
2020-06-21 15:54:13,349+0200 WARN  miktex.core - still open: tmp.tex
```

Comment: Please don't shout so. Correct your title and remove all this uppercase.

Comment: Have you checked the log file (which hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again)?

Comment: I had check it. I'll upload the question because I dont understand why is saying that i do not check updates if I did and have all reinstalled...

Comment: MiKTeX uses the Qt framework under the hood and it seems that there is an initialization problem. To bypass the Qt framework, you can turn on 'Always install missing packages on-the-fly' (in MiKTeX Console).